# SQL Query for insert multiple items in nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js

```
  Shoes.create = (newshoes, result) => {

  sql.query("INSERT INTO shoes SET ? ", newshoes, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    console.log("created shoes: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newshoes });
    result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newshoes });
  });
};
```

in that INSERT INTO shoes SET ? there is supposed to be two parameters (name and description). Doing this `"INSERT INTO shoes SET ? ? ", newshoes, desc` along with this line

```
console.log("created shoes: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newshoes });
result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newshoes });
```

created an error.

I'm learning nodejs and sql query. What is the solution to the error?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you have to specify column names for insert and values in a different way.

So correct query would be:

```
INSERT INTO shoes(column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
```

Look for examples in your database documentation, for PostgreSQL it would be:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: can you do follow up with node js parameters?

Comment: You haven't provided your table and js object schemas